# how to handle the webview's input field when rotate the android phone?

Tags: android, webview, lifecycle

I have an app with show a web login page, I use WebView to finish it. after user input some text for username/password, when user rotate the phone, the activity will recreated, the username/password disappear, user have to input again.

Is there a way I can keep the input text for user.

BTW, I found the browser can handle this case graceful.